# Frame reload not working in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript

A frame is not reloading in Firefox and Chrome, but works in IE.

```
parent.toolbar.location.reload()
```

my function executes in the "builder" frame. i have used this method before and it has worked in all browsers...but not anymore, only works in i.e.

here is frame layout

```
<FRAMESET id="frameset" rows="95,*" cols="*">
  <FRAME noresize="" id="toolbar" name="toolbar" src="Application/toolbar/<?=$id ?>">
  <FRAMESET COLS="81%,*"> 
  <FRAME id="preview" name="preview" src="<?=$preview_url ?>" onload="builder.setPreviewEvents()" >
  <frameset id="tcolor" rows="60,*" cols="*">  
    <FRAME id="colorfr" name="colorfr" scrolling="no" src="<?=$colorfr_url ?>" >
    <FRAME id="builder" name="builder" src="<?=$builder_url ?>" >
    </frameset>
  </FRAMESET> 
  </FRAMESET>
```

Comment: toolbar is the name of the frame that must get reloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
parent.document.getElementById("toolbar").src = parent.document.getElementById("toolbar").src;
```